# Different EntityTypeConfiguration Mappings for Same Class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1

I have two entities that use the same class to represent a name:

**Participant**

```
class Participant
{
  public PersonName Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Judge**

```
class Judge
{
  public PersonName Name { get; set; }
}
```

**PersonName**

```
class PersonName
{
  public string First { get; set; }
  public string Last { get; set; }
  public string Full { get; set; }
}
```

In the table for `Participant`, the `Last` value is a required (non-null) column.  In the table for `Judge`, only the `Full` value is used (and optional).  My problem is that EF is applying the `IsRequired()` from my Participant mapping to the `Judge` instance of `PersonName` and thus failing when only the `Full` value is supplied for a `Judge` Entity.

**Participant Mapping**

```
Property(t => t.Name.Last)
  .IsRequired();
```

**Judge Mapping**

```
Property(t => t.Name.Full)
  .HasMaxLength(100);
```

**Entity Validation Error**

> The Judge.Name.Last field is required.

**Is there a way to avoid this mapping collision other than creating separate `PersonName`-like classes for each mapping situation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to avoid separate class if your `Judge` use only part of `PersonName` values? Judge's Name is a different class.

Storage dependent part of complex type mapping is shared among entities using that type.

Comment: There is no workaround. In code first it looks like you "can" do that but code first is internally translated to metamodel same as used in EDMX and complex type have just single shared definition.